# Populating a double array with double values

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to populate my double array with double values from a loop but I get the following error:
incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Here's my code:

```
public class ThreadGraph extends Thread {

//initializing the variables

public static double x1=0.0;               //left endpoint of interval
public double x2=1.0;                      //right endpoint of interval
public double y=4/(1+Math.pow(x1, 2));     //Deriving the two parallel trapezium lengths
public int n=1000000;                      //The Number of trapezia, 1000000 gives greater accuracy for deriving pi
public double h=(x2-x1)/n;                 //Each trapezium's constant height
public double trapeziaAreasSum=0;          //This variable will store the sum of the areas of the trapezia
static double[]valuesOfx1=new double[1000000];
static double[]valuesOfy=new double[1000000];


//this method divides the area under the curve into trapezia

public void run(){

for(double x1=0.0; x1<1.0; x1=x1+0.000001, y=4/(1+Math.pow(x1,2))){

valuesOfx1[x1] = x1;       //ERROR OCCURS HERE  
valuesOfy[y] = y;          //ERROR OCCURS HERE

}}}
```

What could be the problem? Because the output from the loop is in form of double and I'm attempting to add those results to a double array yet I'm getting an int error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to assign a value to an array's 0.000001 place. That won't fly. Array/List element places are full integers - 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.

A `double` array means it's an array where the values are `double` type, not that the indeces of those values can be doubles.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a non-integer index of an array (so like foo[0.25] doesn't make sense).  You'd either need to use a data type that allows Doubles (uppercase D for the object) as keys (like a LinkedHashMap if iteration order matters) or similar.  Or you use ints for the index and divide to the the double X value for the graph (which would be more space-efficient).  Your call.